# Finding Euler decomposition of a symplectic matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd, symplectic-linear-algebra

A [symplectic matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_matrix) is a $2n\times2n$ matrix $S$ with real entries that satisfies the condition

$$
S^T \Omega S = \Omega
$$
where $\Omega$ is the symplectic form, typically chosen to be $\Omega=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0 & I_N \\ -I_N & 0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. Sympletic matrices form the symplectic group $Sp(2n,\mathbb{R})$. Any symplectic matrix S can be decomposed as a product of three matrices as

\begin{equation}
S = O\begin{pmatrix}D & 0 \\ 0 & D^{-1}\end{pmatrix}O' \quad \quad \forall S \in Sp(2n,\mathbb{R}),
\end{equation}
where $O, O'$ are orthogonal and symplectic - $\operatorname{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{R})\cap \operatorname{O}(2n)$; $D$ is positive definite and diagonal. The form of a matrix that is both symplectic and orthogonal can be given in block form as $O=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}X & Y \\ -Y & X\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, where $XX^T+YY^T=I_N$ and $XY^T-YX^T=0$. The decomposition above is known as Euler decomposition or alternatively as Bloch-Messiah decomposition.

**How can I find the matrices in the decomposition for a given symplectic matrix?**

Apparently, the decomposition is closely related to the singular value decomposition and I think the elements of the matrices $D$ and $D^{-1}$ coincide with the singular values of $S$. Also, I have the impression that the case where it can be assumed that $S$ is also symmetric is easier. Any help, tips or pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: Regarding the SVD: “We also show that if $S$ is symplectic it has the structured [SVD] $S=UDV^*$, where $U$,$V$ are unitary and symplectic, $D=\mathrm{diag}(\Omega, \Omega^{-1})$, and $\Omega$ is positive diagonal.”  [(Xu, 2003)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379503003707). Note this is for complex-valued matrices.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $\varDelta$ stand for your diagonal matrix to write the factorization as $S=O\varDelta O'$. Now, rewrite a bit more:
$$
S=(O\varDelta O^T)(OO')=\varSigma U,
$$
with $\varSigma$ symplectic positive definite and $U$ symplectic and orthogonal. Thus we are looking for a polar decomposition. In fact such a decomposition is unique, and given by
$$
\varSigma=(SS^T)^{1/2},\quad U=(SS^T)^{-1/2}S.
$$
Here we use that a positive semidefinite (symplectic) matrix has a *unique* positive definite (symplectic) square root. Now, once we have $\varSigma$, it can be diagonalized with a symplectic orthogonal linear change $O$ (again quite constructive), and we get the data we sought. For the "basic facts" one can look at Gosson's book, for instance.

Comment: This also shows us that $O'=O^T$ if $S$ is positive semidefinite because, under that condition, $OO' = U = (SS^T)^{-1/2}S = (S^2)^{-1/2}S = I$ (and $O^T = O^{-1}$ by assumption of orthogonality).